# Array/range selection

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

This was  asked in an interview and I was not able to come up with a solution. The scenario is that there is an array of weights (of some items). The cost of choosing an item is **1**. Now if you choose item of weight **w**, you get all items in **range[w, w+4]** as free. The job of the algorithm is to achieve minimum cost and pick all items.

My approach was to have a max heap and traverse the array and while traversing the array calculate the number of items that can be obtained for free by picking up the current item and use max heap to pick items that gaurantee maximum items for free. The interviewer said OK but asked me for a better solution as the traversing part itself cost **O(n^2)**.

**Concrete Example**

```
Weights array: 1 2 3 17 10 
Minimum cost 3: I pick 1, get 2 and 3 for free and then pick both 17 and 10
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure is it right solution, but if you sort your list/array you could traverse your list to find biggest sublist in range [w,w+4]. substract this value from size of your list and your minimum cost.

it will cost you O(NlogN), and most expensive operation will be sorting

```
  List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1 ,2, 3,2, 17, 10);
    Collections.sort(list);//O(logN*N)
    int a=0,b=0;
    do {
        if (list.get(b+1)-list.get(a)<4){
            b++;
        }else{
            a++;
            b++;
        }

    }while(b<list.size()-1);
    int minCost = list.size()-(b-a);
    System.out.println(minCost);
```

This is just example, there might be better solution